# this.checked cannot be modified with checkbox click

Tags: javascript

It seems that the `checked` property of a checkbox cannot be modified, when the event is from the checkbox itself.
Here is small example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.checked=true; return false">
```

The checkbox is not checked after click. Why is `this.checked=true` ignored?

Comment: `return false;` is preventing it from working; is there a reason you need to include that statement?

Comment: Why return false? You are disabling the checkbox by returning false.

Comment: I thought, `return false` will prevent toggling and would be more safe.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing. It's not checked. You are not allowed to toggle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're returning `false`. This value is assigned as the input value. Try this way:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.checked=true">
```

Comment: The return of the `onclick` is not assigned as the input value, it simply prevents the default action (which is to check the checkbox), it's similar (identical?) to `event.preventDefault()`. The browser is preventing both the default action and `this.checked=true` which is being called manually.